# What does the return of true from +isSourceTypeAvailable: in UIImagePickerController mean?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

Apple's documentation advises calling `+isSourceTypeAvailable:` in `UIImagePickerController` to check the availability of a source before using a UIImagePickerController object to pick an image from the source. If the invokation of `UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)` returns true in executing an app, does it mean the camera is available for the app as a source, but for how long?

Can there be a situation that an app checks the availability of the camera resource using `UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)` and receives a response of true, but before the app presents an image picker controller with the source type of Camera, the app becomes inactive and some other app in the device becomes active and puts the camera to use, making the camera unavailable to first app when it becomes active again?

If the mentioned situation is possible, doesn't that mean that a return of true from `UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)` doesn't necessarily mean the camera is available when it is actually used? If a return of true from `UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)` can't guarantee the availability of the camera when it is actually used, how can I ensure an exception is not thrown when using an image picker with the camera its source ([see documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/sourceType))?

Comment: That method checks that the hardware (or camera roll) exists.  It doesn't check if the app has permission to use it (the user will be prompted when the app tries to access for the first time), nor does it reserve the resource for any meaning of the word _reserve_.

Comment: @Avi: You are right about `+isSourceTypeAvailable:` doesn't check if the app has permission to use a source. Permissions are not my concern. According to [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImagePickerController/isSourceTypeAvailable:), "if the camera is already in use, this method returns NO". So, a return of false doesn't mean the hardware doesn't exist. A return of true, doesn't necessarily mean the camera is available when it is used by the app for another app can put it to use first.